# How to recover a replaced user data in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery, google-chrome-extensions

I have uninstalled a chrome extension 3 days ago and I reinstalled it right after. However, I need the user data I had prior reinstalling the said extension. What should be done to restore my previous data in the same extension? The "restore previous session'' was disabled so that's already X.

Comment: You can't; The data was lost when you uninstalled it and reinstalled it.  Any data files the extension would have used were lost, when you uninstalled it, without performing a backup of said data files

Comment: @Ramhound How about getting it through IP address? Still no?

Comment: You get it from your backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin where to find the back-up?

Comment: You get it from a backup you've already taken. If you haven't taken a backup, there won't be one to recover this data from.

Comment: @focedtostudy - Getting what through an IP address?  You cannot recover data that no longer exists on the physical machine that once held the only copy.  When you uninstalled the extension, without first backing up the data, the data for the extension was permanently lost

Comment: Did the Chrome stored it somewhere since I am still using the same machine? @Ramhound